# Can a function is differential at 0 but not continuous?

Tags: calculus

$F(x)=x^2sin(1/x)$ so here this limit exist everywhere but not continuous at 0 why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function *must* be continuous at a point to be differentiable there. Some issues with your question:

- What's the domain that $F$ is defined on? $F$ is clearly undefined at $x=0$, so I'm going to create a new function \begin{align*} f \colon \mathbb R &\to \mathbb R \\
  x &\mapsto \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac 1x\right) & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}\end{align*}
  Now we can reasonably talk about the limit of $f$ at $0$.
- $f$ is in fact continuous at $0$, since $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 = f(0)$.
- $f$ is also differentiable at $0$, since $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \left(\frac 1x\right) = 0.$$

Thus my $f$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable everywhere.

If, instead, we worked with your $F$, not defined at $0$, we would have \begin{align*} F \colon \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb R \\ x &\mapsto x \sin\left(\frac 1x\right)\end{align*}
and we have no issues with division by $0$ now. $0$ is a limit point of $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, so we can reasonably talk about $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)$, which is $0$. But we *cannot* talk about continuity or differentiability there, since the function isn't defined at $x=0$.

For an example of a function which is continuous but not differentiable at a point, consider \begin{align*} g \colon \mathbb R &\to \mathbb R \\ x &\mapsto \begin{cases} x \sin\left(\frac 1x\right) & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x =0\end{cases}\end{align*}

Comment: I heard that this function is pretty famous for some reason, can you tell me why it is special? someone said that it is differential but not continuous at 0